# ODI procedure for calling a stored procedure for delete doesn't work when started with the ODI agent

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I have created a stored PL/SQL  procedure on the DB which needs to delete rows with certain conditions. It is called by an ODI12c procedure, code is in the 'target code' section and is without any parameters:

```
BEGIN
  schema.delete_from_tables;
  END;
```

When I run it through ODI with the ODI agent, it finishes successfully in the operator, but doesn't actually delete the records.
But when I call the same procedure through ODI but with the local agent, it deletes the records; so does when I call it directly in the database.

The user through which the agent makes the connection is the same with which I log in the DB.
Autocommit is 'on', but there's also COMMIT in the stored procedure itself.
The user of the ODI master repository was also granted DELETE on all tables; the agent was restarted - no change.
As a comparison - there are other existing truncate procedures, stored in the same schema and called in the same way through the ODI agent and they work.

Any other suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: when you look at the operator tab and you look at the code that is being executed. is it exactly what you expect. There is definitely something mis-configuered from your set up. Perhaps something is not set up correctly with your topology ? do you have different context? are you sure your pointing to the right context?

Comment: I found the issue, it was actually in the date formatting of the field used to fill in a variable I was using as a condition for the delete. The date variable is using as a source a varchar column which contains a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS. In the initial variant which was not working through the agent, I left the same date format and all logic was based on date columns/variable with format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS. The change I did which made things work was to add a TRUNC function.

Comment: I typically format the date to make sure the oracle back end properly handles the commands. By using eithe a `to_Date` or a `trunc` I think it has something to do between the sending a string between odi and oracle hence the reason I always make sure to send it with a format function.

Comment: Yes, apparently it is a good approach which saves a lot of headache. Thanks for taking the time to answer!